# 2 slick slidera

Tags: jquery, slider, slick.js

У меня 2 slick slidera в макете, мне нужно во втором из них сделать padding 0 50px
когда я задаю padding классу slick-slide у меня у обоих слайдеров появляется этот padding, а нужно лишь у второго, пробовал toggleClass добавил класс к slick-slide и разделил слайдеры по разным файлам js думал так сработает, нет padding все также у обоих слайдеров, подскажите как можно их разделить??

Comment: Из CSS 1) по айди `#id {  } `  2) по классу обрамления `.cls1 .cls_of_slider {  }` взяв допустим в `<div class=cls1>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: ответ пользователя в комментарии] решает вопрос, берем id нужного слайдера и через id уже обращаемся к элементу внутри этого слайдера - это создает необходимую вложенность, которая указывает путь именно к конкретному элементу внутри конкретного слайдера.